# How to use generics with Supabase generated database types?

Tags: typescript, supabase

I'm trying to use TypeScript generics based on the types generated by Supabase from the database, but haven't been able to make it work.
Here is what I'm trying to do:

```js
type DbTables = Database['public']['Tables'];
type TableName = keyof DbTables;
type DbInsert<T extends TableName> = DbTables[T]['Insert'];

async function create<T extends TableName>(insertData: DbInsert<T> | DbInsert<T>[], resourceName: T) {
  try {
    const { data, error } = await supabase.from(resourceName).insert(insertData).select();
    if (error) throw error;
    return data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
},
```

My generic indexed access operator isn't working as I was hoping... would anyone know how to make this work?

My database:

```sql
create table if not exists public.foo (
  id bigint unique generated always as identity,
  bar text not null,
  baz real [] not null,
  qux jsonb not null
);
```

My generated types:

```js
export type Json = string | number | boolean | null | { [key: string]: Json } | Json[];

export interface Database {
  public: {
    Tables: {
      foo: {
        Row: {
          bar: string;
          baz: number[];
          id: number;
          qux: Json;
        };
        Insert: {
          bar: string;
          baz: number[];
          id?: never;
          qux: Json;
        };
        Update: {
          bar?: string;
          baz?: number[];
          id?: never;
          qux?: Json;
        };
      };
    };
    Views: {
      [_ in never]: never;
    };
    Functions: {
      [_ in never]: never;
    };
    Enums: {
      [_ in never]: never;
    };
  };
}
```

The error message I get at `insertData` within the `insert()`:

```
Argument of type 'DbInsert<T> | DbInsert<T>[]' is not assignable to parameter of type '({ foo: { Row: { bar: string; baz: number[]; id: number; qux: Json; }; Insert: { bar: string; baz: number[]; id?: undefined; qux: Json; }; Update: { bar?: string | undefined; baz?: number[] | undefined; id?: undefined; qux?: Json | undefined; }; }; }[T] extends { ...; } ? { ...; }[T]["Insert"] : never) | ({ ...; }[T...'.
  Type 'DbInsert<T>' is not assignable to type '({ foo: { Row: { bar: string; baz: number[]; id: number; qux: Json; }; Insert: { bar: string; baz: number[]; id?: undefined; qux: Json; }; Update: { bar?: string | undefined; baz?: number[] | undefined; id?: undefined; qux?: Json | undefined; }; }; }[T] extends { ...; } ? { ...; }[T]["Insert"] : never) | ({ ...; }[T...'.
    Type '{ bar: string; baz: number[]; id?: undefined; qux: Json; }' is not assignable to type '({ foo: { Row: { bar: string; baz: number[]; id: number; qux: Json; }; Insert: { bar: string; baz: number[]; id?: undefined; qux: Json; }; Update: { bar?: string | undefined; baz?: number[] | undefined; id?: undefined; qux?: Json | undefined; }; }; }[T] extends { ...; } ? { ...; }[T]["Insert"] : never) | ({ ...; }[T...'.
      Type '{ bar: string; baz: number[]; id?: undefined; qux: Json; }' is not assignable to type '{ foo: { Row: { bar: string; baz: number[]; id: number; qux: Json; }; Insert: { bar: string; baz: number[]; id?: undefined; qux: Json; }; Update: { bar?: string | undefined; baz?: number[] | undefined; id?: undefined; qux?: Json | undefined; }; }; }[T] extends { ...; } ? { ...; }[T]["Insert"] : never'.
        Type 'DbInsert<T>' is not assignable to type '({ foo: { Row: { bar: string; baz: number[]; id: number; qux: Json; }; Insert: { bar: string; baz: number[]; id?: undefined; qux: Json; }; Update: { bar?: string | undefined; baz?: number[] | undefined; id?: undefined; qux?: Json | undefined; }; }; }[T] extends { ...; } ? { ...; }[T]["Insert"] : never)[]'.
          Type '{ bar: string; baz: number[]; id?: undefined; qux: Json; }' is missing the following properties from type '({ foo: { Row: { bar: string; baz: number[]; id: number; qux: Json; }; Insert: { bar: string; baz: number[]; id?: undefined; qux: Json; }; Update: { bar?: string | undefined; baz?: number[] | undefined; id?: undefined; qux?: Json | undefined; }; }; }[T] extends { ...; } ? { ...; }[T]["Insert"] : never)[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 29 more.
```

Comment: I don't get an error: https://tsplay.dev/w6L4Ym

Comment: Thanks for your comment. You don't get an error because you haven't injected the `Database` model into the supabase client. See https://tsplay.dev/w2pMbm